# Unable to connect to GCP Redis Memory store from Cloud run spring boot application - although VPC is configured and both are created in same region

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, spring-data-redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I am unable to connect to Google Cloud (GCP) Memory Instance - Redis instance (6.X or 7.X) using the IP and PORT from cloud run developed on Spring boot (3.1.0).

Below is the error:

[Error from Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ShGa.png)

From Cloud Run Response
{
"timestamp": "2023-08-27T06:46:48.837777718",
"message": "Unable to connect to Redis",
"statusCode": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
}

Below are the ways tried.

1. Both the cloud run and Google managed Redis are created in same region.
   Try 1. Cloud Run is configured with the Server less VPC connector and Redis instance has been created. - Connection Type - Private Network access
   Try 2. Just Created Redis instance and on Memory store. - Connection Type - Direct Peering.

Below is the spring Boot Application Config

spring:
data:
redis:
host: <MEMORY_STORE_REDIS_IP>
port: 6378
cache:
cache-names:
- <CACHE_NAME_1>
- <CACHE_NAME_2>
redis:
time-to-live: 60000

Below are the dependencies added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Official documentation on Google Cloud has the details about using the Cloud Compute to use Redis.
But we don't wanted it, we wanted GCP managed instance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.